# How to change color of actionbar in android?

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

I want to change the color of actionbar with a hexadecimal color code. Please help me with step by step procedure to change the color of actionbar. I am new in Android.Please show me all the steps with explanation to change the color.

Comment: `Please help me with step by step procedure` This is **not a tutorial site**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own style in style.xml file

```
<resources>
    ...
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
    ...
</resources>
```

But it's work only from 11 API level. Additionally you can use Toolbar and set background for it.

Or if you want to change it in your code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); //for app compat - call getSupportActionBar()
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
            Color.parseColor("#0086D4"));
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```